Boost 1.85.0 Not Building with VS2022 17.10.3
I'm trying to build Boost C++ library 1.85.0 using Visual Studio 2022 17.10.3 using the following command through Developer Command Prompt.
.\b2 -j8 toolset=msvc-14.3 variant=debug link=static address-model=64 architecture=x86  --build-dir="./obj/x64/debug" --libdir="./lib/x64/debug"  --includedir="./include" --layout=system --no-cmake-config  install
But I'm getting the following error.
don't know how to make <p/D:/<projPath>/boost>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\Hostx64\vcvarsall.bat
and it skipping to build all the boost libraries.
I can see the toolset MSVC 143 already present, not able to understand why this build is failing.
edit: this is found working with older VS2022 17.5, not able to understand what is missing in new version of visual studio

Why build boost? Can't you use the released version directly?

In VS 17.10 the compiler version moved from 14.39 to 14.40 which apparenty confused b2 into believing the toolset was now 144 (which it is not). https://github.com/boostorg/boost/issues/914

@Bop Thanks , I think I should downgrade VS2022 to previous version as a workaround to resolve this issue.
